# In .NET how can I protect a section of code from being executed twice simultaneously

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a .net DLL which calls a c++ DLL which is not thread safe. The .NET DLL is run in IIS. IIS application pool loads a single copy of both DLLs and when two browsers sessions calls the .NET DLL at the same time the c++ DLL Ralph's on its shoes. In certain cases it will cause the application pool to fail in others I get a trappable error.

I attempted to use the Monitor Class to solve my problem like;

```
    Private objSync As Object = New Object
.
.
.
.
        Monitor.Enter(objSync)
        editsErrorHandler(MycPlusPlusCall(_intsmfID, _strEditSetTag, _strEditLayoutTag, strNAACCRRecord,
                                            EE_SKIPFAIL, intErrCount, _ptrThis, _ptrEditsMessagerHandler),
                                           "MycPlusPlusCall")
        objMessageTransport.intMstErrorCount = intErrCount
        objMessageTransport.objMstMessages = _objErrorMessages
        '        Debug.Print("intErrCount=" & intErrCount)
        Monitor.Exit(objSync)
```

MycPlusPlusCall is the c++ DLL call.

This seemed to have no impact.

This is my first foray into calling non thread safe DLLs.

How can I force multiple calls from the application pool to wait until the previous call finishes?

**Edit:**

I moved the Monitor up one level and have succeeded in getting W3WP to crash almost every time. When it crashes I get AppCrash on w3wp with the module being the c++ DLL.

The .NET DLL referenced above is called by a DLL "above" it so I moved the Monitor.Enter & Exit to that level. The new & improved code looks like;

```
    Private Function processRecord(ByVal strInterRecordEditsName As String, _
                                   ByVal objConnection As OracleConnection) As Integer
        Dim strNAACCRRecord As String = buildNAACCRRecord(_objRecord)
        '           Dim strNAACCRRecord As String = _objRecord("NAACCR_RECORD")
        Dim objErrorMessageTransport As ACEEdits50.EditMessageTransport
        Dim intErrCount As Integer = 0
        Dim objErrorMessages As List(Of ACEEdits50.EditMessage) = New List(Of ACEEdits50.EditMessage)
        Dim strDebug As String = "Section 10"
        On Error GoTo processRecordError
        Monitor.Enter(_objACEEdits)
        ' Here is where the heavy lifting is done.
        objErrorMessageTransport = _objACEEdits.runEdits(strNAACCRRecord & Space(_intNAACCRRecordSize - strNAACCRRecord.Length))
        Monitor.Exit(_objACEEdits)
```

**Edit 2:**

So I removed the higher "Monitor.Enter/Exit" and replaced it with SyncLock as recommended below, with the added option of making the object "private shared" So the code looks like;

```
Public Class ACEEdits50
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
.
.
.
.
    Private Shared objSync As Object = New Object

.
.
.
.
    Public Function runEdits(ByVal strNAACCRRecord As String) As EditMessageTransport
.
.
.
.
        SyncLock objSync
            editsErrorHandler(Edit_RunEdits(_intsmfID, _strEditSetTag, _strEditLayoutTag, strNAACCRRecord,
                                                EE_SKIPFAIL, intErrCount, _ptrThis, _ptrEditsMessagerHandler),
                                               "Edit_RunEdits")
            objMessageTransport.intMstErrorCount = intErrCount
            objMessageTransport.objMstMessages = _objErrorMessages
            '        Debug.Print("intErrCount=" & intErrCount)
        End SyncLock
```

I still get the same appCrash.

Comment: What about using mutexes?

Comment: vb.net has the `SyncLock`

Comment: Are you sure this isn't working?  Other than putting the code in a try/finally block (so that the Monitor.Exit is called in all cases), this is the standard pattern.  As @DanielA.White points out, the language-provided `SyncLock` keyword (or `lock` in C#) will do this for you.

Comment: you should also use the same reference to lock on

Comment: Does the objSync need to be marked as static? It's hard to tell if this is inside an instance class, but if it is each instance might have an objSync.

Comment: Is it not working is an interesting question. I am not getting the desired results, that's for sure. When I call the .NET DLL from two different web sessions, it still dies .

Comment: Isn't the problem that the two application pools each have their own memory space and references to the dll, so even a static object in the dll is duplicated in each reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a named Mutex which is used to synchronize between processes in the same OS

```
Public Class ACEEdits50

    Public Function runEdits(ByVal strNAACCRRecord As String) As EditMessageTransport
        Using m = New Threading.Mutex(False, "ACEEdits50")
            While Not m.WaitOne(20000) ' wait 20 seconds for mutex
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for mutex")
            End While
            editsErrorHandler(Edit_RunEdits(_intsmfID, _strEditSetTag, _strEditLayoutTag, strNAACCRRecord, EE_SKIPFAIL, intErrCount, _ptrThis, _ptrEditsMessagerHandler), "Edit_RunEdits")
            objMessageTransport.intMstErrorCount = intErrCount
            objMessageTransport.objMstMessages = _objErrorMessages
            m.ReleaseMutex()
        End Using

    End Function

End Class
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30205711/832052) for more reference in C#

Comment: I did use mutexes, not exactly your code, but it seems to work. Some of the other solutions may also have worked as well. The reason I say that is I was told some calls into the DLL were thread safe, and others weren't. I was only protect those I was told were problematic. I ended up wrapping all calls to the DLL in a mutexes and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
Private Shared protectIt As New Threading.AutoResetEvent(True)
Private Sub TestSimul()
    protectIt.WaitOne() 'block forever
    '
    'code being protected
    ' when done
    protectIt.Set()
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the Threading.AutoResetEvent(True) as defined by @dbasnett, no luck. Same result.